Can I listen to shiurim while feeding a baby with a full diaper?
I was always taught not to bring seforim into the restroom. However, is it acceptable to listen to a shiur while feeding a baby which sounds or smells like it has a full diaper?
If it is not acceptable, can one listen to a shiur while feeding a baby before it has a full diaper? About 50% of the time, my baby will have a BM while drinking a bottle - but it’s not a sure thing, and since he spends so much time eating I would like to use some of that time to listen to shiurim.

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%90_%D7%90

Depends if its breastfeeding and liquid solids or ate bread already.

relevant: Potty in the living room?

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!
